# Prisma Schema Now() + 1 year

Tags: prisma

When defining a schema in prisma, providing now() as default datetime field value is possible.

Is it possible to provide now()+ 1 year as default ?

All my attemps have failed.

Comment: I do think you have to write a database trigger, at least in MySQL, when you want a different default value for a datetime column then `now()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [dbgenerated()](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#dbgenerated) function to call native database functions and assign the return value as the default value of a certain field in your Prisma model.

If you're using PostgreSQL, your Prisma schema would look like this:

```
model foo {
  id Int @id
  createdAt DateTime @default(dbgenerated("NOW() + interval '1 year'"))   // Default value is 1 year from now. 

  // ... other fields
}
```

Comment: And with Mysql, do you know if it is possible?

Comment: can someone link the docs for this or some blog post?

Comment: found it!! [date time functions and operations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html)
this is only for Postgres but others should have sth like it as well